Avoid large intermediate results for conditions on relationships
We use Prisma to access a Postgres database. The query below runs very slowly. A simple modification to the SQL (also shown below) makes it orders of magnitude faster. Is there a way to tell Prisma to use the modified version. I'd like to avoid the slowdown, preferably without resorting to raw SQL.
The Prisma query:
this.prismaService.users.findMany({
  where: {
    events: {
      // they have not had activity since timeWindowEnd
      none: {
        timestamp: {
          gte: timeWindowEnd,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

This generates the following SQL
SELECT *
FROM "public"."users" AS "t1"
WHERE (
        ("t1"."id") NOT IN (
            SELECT "t5"."user_id"
            FROM "public"."events" AS "t5"
            WHERE (
                    "t5"."timestamp" >= '2024-07-01T11:46:00'
                    AND "t5"."user_id" IS NOT NULL
                )
            -- GROUP BY "t5"."user_id"  -- This would fix the slowdown
        )
    )
ORDER BY "t1"."id" ASC

When executing the query, Postgres materializes the subquery. Since users can have thousands of events, doing so is very costly.
If I modify the subquery, adding the GROUP BY that is commented out above, then the intermediate result is much smaller, and the query completes almost instantly.
Is there a way to get the fast behavior without using raw SQL?

Edited to add query plans for the two versions:
This is the slow version. Note that it materializes about 150k intermediate rows:
 Index Scan using users_pkey on public.users t1  (cost=3255.46..247110031.77 rows=7422 width=1751) (actual time=119.698..218304.
278 rows=13094 loops=1)
   Output: t1.id, [... 17 columns omitted]
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1750
   Buffers: shared hit=10733, temp read=3342203 written=242
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Materialize  (cost=3255.17..36189.31 rows=143833 width=4) (actual time=0.001..8.240 rows=131478 loops=14844)
           Output: t5.user_id
           Buffers: shared hit=5577, temp read=3342203 written=242
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.events t5  (cost=3255.17..34908.15 rows=143833 width=4) (actual time=5.537..21.790 rows=1413
24 loops=1)
                 Output: t5.user_id
                 Recheck Cond: (t5."timestamp" >= '2024-07-01 11:46:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                 Filter: (t5.user_id IS NOT NULL)
                 Heap Blocks: exact=5054
                 Buffers: shared hit=5577
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_timestamp_index  (cost=0.00..3219.21 rows=143838 width=0) (actual time=5.01
3..5.013 rows=141324 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (t5."timestamp" >= '2024-07-01 11:46:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                       Buffers: shared hit=523
 Planning Time: 0.183 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 10
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.941 ms, Inlining 6.450 ms, Optimization 42.365 ms, Emission 22.165 ms, Total 71.920 ms
 Execution Time: 218312.152 ms

This is the faster version with the GROUP BY:
 Index Scan using users_pkey on public.users t1  (cost=35374.63..36142.55 rows=7422 width=1751) (actual time=57.621..62.388 rows
=13094 loops=1)
   Output: t1.id, [... 17 columns omitted]
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1750
   Buffers: shared hit=10733
   SubPlan 1
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=35267.73..35353.02 rows=8529 width=4) (actual time=56.818..57.077 rows=1750 loops=1)
           Output: t5.user_id
           Group Key: t5.user_id
           Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 529kB
           Buffers: shared hit=5577
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.events t5  (cost=3255.17..34908.15 rows=143833 width=4) (actual time=8.642..36.639 rows=1413
24 loops=1)
                 Output: t5.id, [... 16 columns omitted]
                 Recheck Cond: (t5."timestamp" >= '2024-07-01 11:46:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                 Filter: (t5.user_id IS NOT NULL)
                 Heap Blocks: exact=5054
                 Buffers: shared hit=5577
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_timestamp_index  (cost=0.00..3219.21 rows=143838 width=0) (actual time=7.90
7..7.907 rows=141324 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (t5."timestamp" >= '2024-07-01 11:46:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                       Buffers: shared hit=523
 Planning Time: 0.185 ms
 Execution Time: 63.114 ms


Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query? And the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your question.

@FrankHeikens OK, added the query plans. The tables are nothing too special. Users have many Events.

NOT IN isn't a great solution here, but it also looks like you don't have an index on user_id (in combination) with timestamp. That might help. CREATE INDEX idx_user_id_timestamp ON events(user_id, "timestamp");. The name "timestamp" is imho not the best one, it doesn't say anything about what kind of data it is, just the type of data.

Thanks, @FrankHeikens. The NOT IN is what Prisma generates; I wouldn't know how to change it (but I might have to resort to raw SQL). I'll consider the user_id+timestamp index. That said, the root of the problem seems to be the unnecessary "materialize", any idea why Postgres does that and how to prevent it?

Ended up with a correlated NOT EXISTS subquery (see own answer to the question). Correction to what I wrote before: the slow performance of the original probably wasn't in the materialize, but in the loop that tested all the users against all the user ids from matching events... I have no idea why Postgres did not sort or hash the sets.

sorting and hashing (also) depends on your database configuration.

We've ended up using the following query, with a correlated subquery. This seems to perform even better than NOT IN plus GROUP BY. The user id + timestamp index, suggested by @FrankHeikens, also helped for the correlated subquery (but not for the original version).
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE 1 = 1
  --they have not had activity since timeWindowEnd
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM events e3
    WHERE e3.user_id = u.id
      AND e3.timestamp >= '2024-07-01T11:46:00'
  )
;

There is an open Prisma issue for optimizing some and none relation filters: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/24524
